# Asynchronous code in nested forEach loop- react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, foreach

I have input data that is formatted as such:

```
[ [4, 1, 2], [2, 5] ]
```

I want to make an api call for each of the numbers in the array, and have output as such:

```
[ [response_4, response_1, response_2], [response_2, response_5] ]
```

I've been stuck on this logic for two days-- I can't get my return array formatted correctly. It instead returns:

```
[ response_4, response_1, response _2, response_2, response_5 ]
```

I know I'm doing something wrong in terms of using promises/async, and also I know I need to reset temp to length = 0 at some point, but every time I add that in, it will simply return [] as my output. Any advice/help?

```
const getNumData = (data) => {
  let temp = []
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    data.forEach((outerArray) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        outerArray.forEach((number) => {
          return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/number?id=${number}`, {method: 'GET',})
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            temp = this.state.seqDone.concat(responseJson[0]);
            this.setState({
              seqDone: temp
            })
            console.log(temp)
          })
        })
        if (this.state.seqDone) {
          console.log(this.state.seqDone)
          resolve(this.state.seqDone);
        } else {
          reject(Error('Sequences not found'));
        }
      })
    });
    if (this.state.seqDone) {
      console.log(this.state.seqDone)
      resolve(this.state.seqDone);
    } else {
      reject(Error('Sequences not found'));
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in this way

```js
const nestedPromise = async (items = []) => {
  return await Promise.all(
    items.map(async item => {
      if (Array.isArray(item) && item.length) {
        return await nestedPromise(item)
      }
      // return await call to your function
      return 'response-' + item
    })
  )
}

const items = [ [4, 1, 2], [2, 5] ]
nestedPromise(items).then(results => {
  console.log(results)
})
```

Promise.all accepts array of functions as arguments, thoses functions will be executed asynchronously. In your case you just have to use it recursively

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up doing something similar

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution. Do you think that this can be the right answer ? Can you mark it as the right one if it does please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  fetchData = (item) => {
    return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pose?id=${item}`)
    .then (response => response.json())
  }

  constructArray = (items) => {
    Promise.all(items.map(nestedArray => {
    return Promise.all(nestedArray.map(this.fetchData))
    }
  ))
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
  })

  }
```

Comment: This is the solution that I ended up going with